# Grid distribution of objects based on their center

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow, alignment

I am trying to align objects in **Illustrator** in a grid.

[image]

(The grid must not show in the final image).
I want the center of each object to be aligned vertically **and** horizontally, as if it were at the crossing of each line on this grid.

***Objects are not the same size.***

When I use **Illustrator**’s **Vertical Distribute Center** option, I get this (note the red lines = not good):

[image]

but what I want is this (note the blue lines = good):

[image]

If I group my objects horizontally first, then distribute the space vertically, I get this (red = not good):

[image]

<sub>*(My objects are not rectangles, but a logo of the same company name. Under each instance is the name of the country-specific branch, which is what makes each object a different size). Image 2 was done in Blender with Oscurart alignment tools*</sub>

### *How do I grid-space objects in Illustrator?*

Comment: Maybe it's me.. but I'm completely confused as to what's being asked here. Something regarding alignment I get.. but I'm having some trouble deciphering what the *problem* is. The images are, to me, poorly labeled and unclear. You cite "image 3" but I see either 2 or 5 images depending on how you are determining what an image constitutes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I rewrote the question to try and explain my goal better

Answer (score 2):

It would seem to me that it's a multi-step alignment procedure, not a simple one or two click issue.

- **Align each side** to itself on vertical centers.
- **Align the top objects** on horizontal centers using one of them as the **key object** 
  *(To set a key object, select everything to be aligned then, with the Selection Tool, click the object a second time and it should be set as the key object indicated by a bolder highlight)*
- **Align the bottom objects** on horizontal centers using one of them as the **key object**
- **Distribute Spacing** on the side containing equal sized objects
- **Align the interior objects** on horizontal centers setting the distributed side's object as key objects.

[image]

I realize it's not a simple one or two click solution, but it will be accurate.

A second option would be draw a rectangle around *each* object with no fill and no stroke which is the same size for every object. Align the object to the center of the "hollow" rectangle. Group this "hollow" rectangle with the object. Then you could align and distribute things as if they were all the same size because though bounding area would be, even though the visible area would be different.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I'm glad my rewrite helped you understand my issue. I'm baffled as to why there isnt' a simpler way to do this... (I have 7 columns of 32 logos so I'm hoping there's a faster way!)

Comment: Yeah there's really not much available if the objects vary in dimensions You can align/distribute on center but that's really never going to accomplish a "smart" alignment. All I can think of is to use symbols of the same size, set up a grid and then swap the symbols for the desired, varied, objects. I don't really think that would be any faster though.

Answer (score 0):

You can make such an action that selects each one of your placement rectangles (you must use the 'select via note' from the Actions flyout menu, and have attribute notes written into your rectangles (which could be just clear paths)), that selects each rectangle and fits your artboard to it. Then it selects your logo group, or whichever element you want aligned, and you can have it align to center vertically and horizontally. Your alignment mode must be set to 'artboard' though. So your action will go through all of the rectangles, playing a block of alignment operations for each object. At the end, you may have the action select a large clear rectangle which would be the size of your original artboard and then 'reset' the artboard by fitting it back to this rectangle. You must have drawn this rectangle first. And this way, you can automate some of it.